# what does noun +とする mean?

Tags: meaning, nuances

I'm aware of some of the meanings of とする but in this sentence

> 聞きおわると、彼は愕然としていた。

愕然 is apperently a noun that has something to do with feelings 
**astonishment / shock etc**

and one of the definitions of とする states that it has the meaning of 
to feel (e.g. after sound symbolism or psychological experience word)/to look/to feel like.

I don't quite understand the definition but i've just assumed that とする is used to express feelings but i can't find any examples other than with 愕然.
In fact when i look for sentences with 愕然 they all have とする attached and i don't understand whether it's exclusively used with this noun or are there other examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some similar phrases in the order they came up in my mind.

- 戦々恐々【せんせんきょうきょう】とする
- 嬉々【きき】とする (eg 嬉々として話す)
- のんびりとする (also written as のんびりする)
- 堂々【どうどう】とする
- 悄然【しょうぜん】とする
- 恍惚【こうこつ】とする (eg 恍惚とした表情)
- 憮然【ぶぜん】とする (eg 憮然とした表情)
- 凜【りん】とする (eg 凜とした表情)
- ゆっくりとする (also written as ゆっくりする)
- こそこそとする (also written as こそこそする)
- 飄々【ひょうひょう】とする (eg 飄々とした態度)

Please consult your favorite dictionary for the meanings because I really don't know how to translate many of these words naturally into English :)

Among these, のんびりと, ゆっくりと and こそこそと seem to belong to a difference category because と is optional and they can work as standalone adverbs which directly modify a verb without する (eg, ゆっくり(と)過ごす, のんびり(と)考える). 堂々と also works as a standalone adverb for whatever reason (eg, 堂々と語る). None of the words in the list works as a na-adjective.

For other (fairly difficult) kanji words, they are usually followed by ～とする/～として/～とした, and と cannot be omitted. And yes, they are all related to emotions and/or facial expressions.

Comment: Can i use for example 戦々恐々と without する to modify a verb or is it only possible with  のんびりと and similar words?

Answer (score 2):

There are many and many more samples of "とする" which means "to be" or "to feel something", especially (but not only) in Japanese literature:

「すでにショック状態で意識も朦朧としていた」 "I was already shocked and fainted"

「周りはしんとしていた」 "The surroundings were silent"

「釈然としないな」 "I'm not fully satisfied" (with explanation)

Answer (score 0):

There are many  [ ... 然とする ] words. 　　　　　 They are fancy ways of expressing : shocked, angy, scared, ....... etc. ......

奮然とする (inspired)　　　　　騒然とする (commotion)

呆然とする (at a loss, aghast)　　　　　憤然とする (angry)

判然とする (becomes clear)　　　　　慄然とする (scared)

嬌然とする (coquettish ?)

「憮然とする」　　　混然とする　　　　あ然とする　　　　粛然とする　　　得意然とする

「 Noun- 然とする」  「女王然とする」  「先生然とする」  「紳士然とする」

---

Present tense:　　　　  愕然とする 　　　　 --- 　　　　愕然としている

Past tense: 　　　　愕然とした

But 愕然とした sounds like it only describes the moment of shock, so
愕然としていた is more often used, to show that the shock lasted some time.

> http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/24asupekuto.html
>
> 「存在する」や関係・感覚を表す動詞のいくつかは「Ｖ－ている」の形にもなります。 意味の違いは ほとんど ありません。
>
> 存在する：存在している　　　　　　違う：違っている
>
> 含む：含んでいる          　　　　　　　　感じる：感じている

It's interesting when a famous linguist says that there's almost no difference in the meanings of similar words (expressions).

Answer (score 0):

According to the dictionary, 愕然 is always used with とする (or として):
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/11470/meaning/m0u/%E6%84%95%E7%84%B6/

So instead of memorizing 愕然 and とする as two separate words, you should memorize 愕然とする as one single verb.

It is more difficult trying to understand them separately.